# Empty WMS popup (geoext)

Tags: wms, geoext, popup, getfeatureinfo

I have a problem with my application and more precisely the pop up that appears empty.

```
controls.push(new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({    
    autoActivate: true,
    infoFormat: "application/vnd.ogc.gml",
    maxFeatures: 3,
    eventListeners: {
        "getfeatureinfo": function(e) {
            var items = [];
            Ext.each(e.features, function(feature) {
                items.push({
                    xtype: "propertygrid",
                    title: feature.fid,
                    source: feature.attributes
                });
            });
            new GeoExt.Popup({
                title: "Feature Info",
                width: 200,
                height: 200,
                layout: "accordion",
                map: app.mapPanel,
                location: e.xy,
                items: items
            }).show();
        }
    }
}));
```

[image: empty popup]

Comment: sorry @BORUSSEN11 When I added code block to your question the image fell out somehow. Can you add it back?

Comment: Have you checked with debug tools if there is a repsonse coming back from Geoserver? you could also use console.log to test that: "getfeatureinfo": function(e) {console.log(e.features); ......

Comment: @Brad Nesom just fixed the formatting, so that the image is visible again ;)

Answer (score 2):

A common reason for such an error is the Same-Origin-Policy.

If your Webserver is serving on Port 80 and Geoserver on Port 8080 for example then your request can be blocked because of a violation of the Same Origin Policy.

[image]

If that's the reason in your case just add a proxy.cgi, adapt it to your needs (correct settings/path for the python shebang, add your geoserver url to the allowed hosts) and set the OL-ProxyHost:

OpenLayers.ProxyHost="/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url=";

https://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#ProxyHost

Then it should work:
[image]